# Using SQL Server to replace line breaks in columns with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large table of data where some of my columns contain line breaks. I would like to remove them and replace them with some spaces instead.

Can anybody tell me how to do this in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google the `REPLACE` function.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, depending on how the line breaks are encoded:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, '
', ' ')
    where col like '%
%';
```

That is, in SQL Server, a string can contain a new line character.

Comment: This will not work with all flavours of line breaks, and - very erronous! - it would break, if it was indented/formatted due to readability...

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon's answer should work, but in case you're not sure how your line breaks are encoded, you can use the `ascii` function to return the character value.  For example:

```
declare @entry varchar(50) = 
'Before break
after break'

declare @max int = len(@entry)
; with CTE as (
    select 1 as id
          , substring(@entry, 1, 1) as chrctr
          , ascii(substring(@entry, 1, 1)) as code
    union all
    select id + 1
          , substring(@entry, ID + 1, 1)
          , ascii(substring(@entry, ID + 1, 1))
    from CTE
    where ID <= @max)

select chrctr, code from cte

print replace(replace(@entry, char(13) , ' '), char(10) , ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending where your text is coming from, there are different encodings for a line break. In my test string I put the most common.

First I replace all `CHAR(10)` (Line feed) with `CHAR(13)` (Carriage return), then all doubled CRs to one CR and finally all CRs to the wanted replace (you want a blank, I put a dot for better visability:

**Attention: Switch the output to "text", otherwise you wont see any linebreaks...**

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100)='test single 10' + CHAR(10) + 'test 13 and 10' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'test single 13' + CHAR(13) + 'end of test';

SELECT @text

DECLARE @ReplChar CHAR='.';

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text,CHAR(10),CHAR(13)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(13),CHAR(13)),CHAR(13),@ReplChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, means I have a column having values with line breaks in it. I use the query

```
update `your_table_name` set your_column_name = REPLACE(your_column_name,'\n','')
```

And this resolves my issue :)

Basically '\n' is the character for Enter key or line break and in this query, I have replaced it with no space (which I want)

Keep Learning :)
 zain

Answer (score 0):

Based on Behnam response:

In my case I needed to replace with other chars like \n\r because while I'm not using SQL Server 2022 where it can build json objects with JSON_OBJECT I did build it manually and then the break lines it broken the structure of the json, so I replaced CHAR(10) AND CHAR(13) as it's shown in the following code:

```
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(10), '\n', CHAR(13), '\r'))
```

I hope it helps someone.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-object-transact-sql